# Java generated code from wadl don't have implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, code-generation, wadl

I'm new to java code generation from WADL, I used cxf-wadl2java-plugin and it works fine, the problem is that the generated code contains the resource code but no implementation as such:

```
/**
 * Created by Apache CXF WadlToJava code generator
**/
package wadl.client;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import wadl.Response;

@Path("/path")
public class PathResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json" })
    public Response get(@QueryParam("q") String q, @QueryParam("attr") String attr) {
        //TODO: implement
        return null;
    }

}
```

Is there any mean to get an implementation when the code generation is done?

How do I us this class (injection??)?

How do I set the data return type? (json, xml, Response object?)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language):

> WADL models the resources provided by a service and the relationships
>   between them

It however, does not state anything on the logic behind such resources.

Long story short, the WADL should explain/point out what resources must your system expose, however it does not explain how are these resources implemented, which is usually ideal since Web Services are usually used to *simply* expose a set of functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and thanks to wikipedia, my question isn't about the purpose of WADL, the subject here is about the generation tool I used.

Comment: @BelkacemREBBOUH: That the definition should point out is that there is now way (as far as I know at least) that the tool can infer what internal logic does your method need to have.